# Accepting a known number of integers on a single line in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I know there is a similar question already asked, so let me apologize in advance. I am new to Java and before this, my only programming experience is QBasic.

So here is my dilemma: I need to accept 2 integer values and I would like to be able to enter both values on the same line, separated by a space (IE: Enter "45 60" and have x=45 and y=60).

From what I have seen, people are suggesting arrays, but I am weeks away from learning those... is there a simpler way to do it? We have gone over "for", "if/else", and "while" loops if that helps. I don't have any example code because I don't know where to start with this one.

I have the program working with 2 separate calls to the scanner... just trying to shorten/ clean up the code. Any ideas??

Thanks!

//UPDATE:

Here is the sample so far. As I post this, I am also reading the scanner doc.
And I don't expect you guys to do my homework for me. I'd never learn that way.
The println at the end it my way of checking that the values were stored properly.

```
public static void homework(){
    Scanner hwScan = new Scanner(System.in);   
    System.out.println("Homework and Exam 1 weights? ");
    int hwWeight = hwScan.nextInt();
    int ex1Weight=hwScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(hwWeight+"   "+ex1Weight); 
}
```

Comment: If you have the program working, then what's your question? How could we help uou shorten or cleanup the code without seeing any of it?

Comment: The program is still in its infancy. I am currently working to get an example ready. Right now, I can enter the int's on 2 separate lines. All I want to do is be able to enter 2 int's on the same line and have it split into 2 variables.

Comment: And the code for that is? Have you read the javadoc of Scanner? We can help you with your code, give you hints. But we won't do your homework for you. So post your code, or your question will be closed.

Comment: Even an example syntax would help. I don't even need you to re-write any of my code.

Comment: Your code already does what you want.

Comment: Wow, I just tried it. I kinda feel stupid now.... well thanks for responding so quick. I will be sure to do a bit more research before coming to you guys. At least I know how to use this site now.

Comment: It would be nice if you upvote all the given answers (if you feel the helped you)

Comment: I am not rep level 15 yet, or I would...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even simple `scanner.nextInt()` would work for you like below:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    int y = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("x = " + x + " y = " + y);
```

Output:

1 2
x = 1 y = 2

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to accept two integer numbers you could do something like this:

```
String input = System.console().readLine(); //"10 20"
//String input = "10 20";
String[] intsAsString = input.split(" ");
int a = Integer.parseInt(intsAsString[0];
int b = Integer.parseInt(intsAsString[1]);
```

intsAsString is an array, in simple terms, that means it stores n-strings in one variable. (Thats very simplistic, but since you look at arrays more closely later you will see what i mean).

Be sure to roughly understand each line, not necessarily what exactly the lines do but conceptually: Read data form Console, parse the line so you have the two Strings which represent the two ints, then parse each string to an int. Otherwise you will have a hard time in later on.

Comment: would this allow the integers to be entered by the user though? I honestly can't tell... I have been programming for 4 weeks now.